# What online games are available, which are well-suited to interactive game play with viewers in a Twitch stream?

Tags: windows, game, multi-user

I am looking for options of online games, which would be suitable for play with viewers in a Twitch stream.  Fibbage (and other games in the Jackbox Party Pack) and Cards Against Humanity come to mind as examples.

Requirements:

- Either free, or a one time payment by the host only (viewers play free if the host buys the game)
- Easy to pick up and play a game without time/effort commitment (MMOs, Hearthstone, etc. would be examples of games that do NOT pass this test; someone who has never played should be able to painlessly join in)
- Supports at LEAST 4 players per game
- Should be enjoyable and comfortable for both males and females
- Obviously should at least run on Windows (cross platform is all the merrier)

If possible, please indicate whether a listed game includes a focus on inappropriate language/sexual themes/etc.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: At least Windows, thought cross platform would be a bonus.